# Adobe AIR app that will upload video files to a NodeJS server

Tags: node.js, air, adobe

I want to build an Adobe AIR app that will upload video files to a NodeJS server, receive a notification when the files are done being processes, and then prompt the user to download the finished video file.

Possible?
I am not asking for specific code solution, rather a general yes/no as to the feasibility of this solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes it's possible, I am using node.js for server side and flash/flex/AIR for client side, so I am confident about this.

Comment: Hi Dmitry, may I ask what particular node solution you are using?

Comment: What does you mean node solution? If you're asking about node version currently installed on my system - I have Node.js v0.10.29. For video uploading it doesn't matter.

Comment: Thanks. Just having a problem in properly constructing my File.upload on the client side.

Comment: Should I be using UrlLoader instead? so UrlLoader.load(request) instead of File.upload(request) ?

Comment: You shoul use  File.upload(request) or FileReference.upload()